# Passing object to a request and convert Property name to JsonProperty name in C#

Tags: c#

I have a method that is meant to post a request. Basically, this method takes an uri, a userRequest to send as Json payload and a bearer token.

```
public async Task<UserResponse> CreateUser(Uri url, UserRequest userRequest, string token)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    req.Content = new StringContent(
        userRequest.ToString(),
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json"
    );
    var response = await client.SendAsync(req); 
    string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    UserResponse returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(output);
    return returnValue;
}
```

My issue is that the response is an error 422.
My request model is the following :

```
public class UserRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isadmin")]
    public bool IsAdmin{ get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserRequest(string email, bool sysadmin, string password)
    {
        Email = email;
        IsAdmin = isAdmin;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

In fact I do think my issue is that I don't pass correctly the object in the post request or that the keys are taken from the model and not from property name.

I mean that I send

```
{ "Email": "myMail@mail.com", "Password": "passwd", "IsAdmin": true }
```

Instead of :

{ "email":  "myMail@mail.com", "password": "passwd", "isadmin": true }

My question is to know if there's a way to use JsonProperty names instead of Properties names

```
req.Content = new StringContent(
    userRequest.ToString(),
    Encoding.UTF8,
    "application/json"
);
```

Comment: `a userRequest to send as Json payload` you didn't post any code that serializes to JSON. Use `JsonConvert.Serialize` instead of `ToString()`. Your class doesn't overload `ToString()` so you end up calling `Object.ToString()` which returns the object's type name

Comment: So obvious :) thanks ! JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest) works perfectly... I should have thought about it... Friday is a hard day !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Newtonsoft.JSON to Serialize the object?

JsonConvert.Serialize(userRequest) should do the trick